# Can't read strings from dbf file (but can read Number type data correctly) Java, DBFReader

Tags: java, inputstream, dbf

I'm currently using DBFReader (github.com/jamel/dbf) to read DBF files, but when it outputs what I believe are hash representations of the data? However, for columns where the data is numeric, it's fine.

Here's the code snippet (very basic code):

```
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./src/data/dbf/Room_20040610.DBF");
    DbfReader reader = new DbfReader(inputStream);

    Object[] row;
    while ((row = reader.nextRecord()) != null) {
        System.out.println(row[1]);
    }

    reader.close();
```

The output of string type data

```
[B@54b749a5
[B@4d441b16
[B@324e68fb
[B@39ce508a
[B@1809b1ac
[B@246f9f88
[B@1c52ac68
[B@77b4ee5e
[B@78d9ab8
[B@61a8a9e7
```

When this is expected:

```
1101
1101
1101
1101
1101
1101
1101
1101
1101
1101
```

First of all, just a few assumptions out of the way:

1. The dbf file is not corrupt or unreadable.
2. The "string" data that comes up as a hash when I try System.out.println contains English and  non-English characters, but neither works.
3. I'm using Eclipse on a Mac. (I wonder if it's different on Windows?)

Would appreciate any input regarding how to correct read strings with DBFReader.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [B@ in the object hash indicates that its a byte array, so you would need to do:

`new String((byte[]) row[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
System.out.println(row[1]);
```

try casting `row[1]` to the expected type. For example

```
SOP(((String) row[1]).toString());   //if String is expected or
SOP(((String) row[1]));              //should also work
```

`[B@54b749a5` is getting printed because `row[1]` returns an `Object` type and then when you pass it to `println` it uses the `toString()` definition provided by `Object` class.

Comment: I tried casting, and it didn't work. Thanks anyway. :)